# OpenCV2 - Suppress compression dialog box when instantiating a VideoWriter object

Tags: python, opencv, compression

In Python **OpenCV 2.4.9**, when instantiating a `VideoWriter` object with the usual instruction:

```
video = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", -1, 25, (640,480))
```

I get the following annoying dialog box that asks me to choose between the various options of compression modalities.

[image]

I need to iteratively create `VideoWriter` objects in order to construct a large video dataset and I am wondering if there is any way to set the compression modality only once and get rid of that dialog box popping up at every new `VideoWriter` instantiation.

I really need to automate this process, so any help would be truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works smoothly:

```
video = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", 1, 25, (640,480))
```

My system:

- Python 2.7.15
- OpenCV 2.4.9

Comment: It does, because for you it works with the codec for which `cv2.cv.FOURCC` function returns `1`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the parameter for the constructor of the `VideoWriter()` . When you pass `-1` for the second parameter, that means you re asking for the window to pop up. If you want to choose the codec beforehand, you can do so by setting it to integer corresponding to the given codec.

So the code would look something like this:

```
# for OCV == 3.X.X
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', '2', '6', '4')

#for OCV == 2.X.X
fourcc = cv2.cv.FOURCC(*'X264')
video = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 25, (640,480))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply. Unfortunately the solution you provide applies only to OpenCV version 3 and above.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort in answering my question. Unfortunately doing `fourcc = cv2.cv.FOURCC(*'X264')` results in empty videos being saved on local memory.

Comment: Try different codec. H264 might not work for you. See posisble codecs [here](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php)